# setInterval not working though it should

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I am trying to use setInterval and it just isn't working, I don't know what the reason for it, I even just copied a setInterval function from a tutorial website but it still is not working...

```
function reload() {
console.log("reload");
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 1000);
}
```

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <title>php!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="basic.css"/>
    <script src="auto-refresh.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body onload="reload()">

  <?php

  ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  include 'headline.php';

  ?>
  <iframe id="chat-window" name="chat-frame" src="chat.php" height="500" width="800">

  </iframe>
  <form method="post"  target="chat-frame" action="chat.php">
    <input id="sentence" type="text" name="enter" placeholder="Enter whatever you like" value="<?php echo $_POST["enter"];?>" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the `console.log("reload");` does work

Comment: Have you ticked the "Don't allow this page to open new pop-ups" checkbox? Use `console.log` also in the interval function, that might work better.

Comment: @Teemu nope and either way, even if I'm writing `console.log()` instead `alert()` it still doesn't work

Comment: And no error messages in the console?

Comment: None, not even a clue.
If it matters (and I don't think it is, it is a `.php` file and not `.html`)

Comment: The code is included in auto-refresh.js? Are you sure it is loaded?

Comment: It is and I do. As I said, the `console.log()` before the setInterval IS working

Comment: An effective pop-up blocker in action maybe? Or a cached version of the js file? Or a troll post?

Comment: Nope, just tested it, I disabled the ad blocker and still nothing

Answer (score 1):

I am not sur what is your issue but here is a working version

[image]

```js
function reload() {
console.log("reload");
setInterval(function(){ alert("Hello"); }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<body onload="reload()">
</body>
```

Comment: It still does not work. I copy - pasted your code it still it isn't working... the page does not alert though it is printing "reload" to the console

Comment: i did update my answer with a screen shot , if it still not working please consider updating your browser

Comment: It did work earlier, I don't know why it stopped working, I used Ctrl+Z to go back to when it did work but still nothing...